# Jquery mobile styles missing in Magento site

Tags: php, jquery, magento, jquery-mobile

I am using jquery mobile to develop mobile version of my magento site. My problem is that, i am not getting jquery mobile's button and drop down styles for a module i installed recently.

The module is a storepickup set up for customers. I am missing its jquery mobile styles in my checkout page, under shipping method option. I have two drop downs and a textbox under it. It shows ordinary styles rather jquery  mobile's styles.

The problem is that, when i define a button,

```
<input type="button" value="Save" />
```

in my file 'pickup.phtml' it comes with ordinary styles. But if i enter with manually written jquery styles such as

```
    <div class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-fullsize ui-btn-block ui-btn-up-c" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-icon="" data-iconpos="" data-theme="c" data-inline="false" data-mini="false" aria-disabled="false">
<span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all">
<span class="ui-btn-text">Continue</span>
</span>
<button class="button ui-btn-hidden" onclick="shippingMethod.save()" type="button" aria-disabled="false">
</button>
</div>
```

Its comes with Jquery mobile styles. ie Styles are present in the page but button is not picking up it by default.

Any solution?

Comment: How to design the magento website to develop a mobile version using jquery mobile what are the basic requirements are needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it Finally................!!!!

Create trigger fixed it! Find page where jquery-mobile styles are missing and paste...

```
jQuery('.yourdivsclass').trigger("create");
```

Hope it may be helpful for some one else.